# Toggle button work but don't show list content in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've written a toggle function to show a list when I press a button. although I've tested via console.log and it returns a  but the div doesn't have any content inside it, also the list isn't created below the button as it should, I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [
      { name: "Leonardo", age: "26" },
      { name: "Margarete", age: "50" },
      { name: "Marcelo", age: "50" }
    ],
    otherState: "some other value",
    showPersons: false
  };

  togglePersonsHandler = () => {
    const doesShow = this.state.showPersons;
    this.setState({ showPersons: !doesShow });
  };

  render() {
    const style = {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      font: "inherit",
      border: "1x solid blue",
      padding: "8px",
      cursor: "pointer"
    };

    let persons = null;

    if (this.state.showPersons) {
      persons = (
        <div>
          {this.state.persons.map(person => {
            return
            <Person name={person.name} age={person.age} />;
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>MY APP</h1>
        <button style={style} onClick={this.togglePersonsHandler}>
          Toggle Persons
        </button>
        {persons}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

As requested the Person component

```
import React from 'react';

import './Person.css';

const person = ( props ) => {
    return (
        <div className="Person">
            <p onClick={props.click}>I'm {props.name} and I am {props.age} years old!</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} value={props.name} />
        </div>
    )
};

export default person;
```

Comment: Code seems quite right, can you please share the `Person` component?

Comment: i've added the person component in the question, thanks!

Comment: try moving <Person name={person.name} age={person.age} />; above such that it looks like (in the same line):
`return <Person name={person.name} age={person.age} />;`

The code seems to be working for me.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-sound-zrefz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's it, it worked!! Thanks Vishal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved when i moved the content after return statement the same line. Thanks to [Vishal Dhawan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9342859/vishal-dhawan) for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional to render the div directly in your JSX. You can do something like this:

```
  <div className="App">
    <h1>MY APP</h1>
    <button style={style} onClick={this.togglePersonsHandler}>
      Toggle Persons
    </button>
    { this.state.showPersons ? 
        <div>
          {this.state.persons.map(person => {
            <Person name={person.name} age={person.age} />;
          })}
        </div>
      : null
    }
  </div>
```

This will only add the div to the DOM if and only if `showPersons` resolves to a thruthy value.

Comment: didn't work, a div is added after the button is pressed but it doesn't have any content